# How to log a message from a VCL or FMX app in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, logging, firemonkey, console.log, vcl

I want to know if it's possible to log a message into the Messages panel in the IDE from your code.

Like how in JavaScript you can do `console.log` to log a message to the browser console. I want to use this for debugging purposes.

How can I log something to the Messages panel when running the app from Delphi IDE? Is this possible?

I want to log it here:
[Delphi Messages Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5FBa.png)

I've tried looking online for ways, but could not find any

Comment: If you are interested merely in Windows applications for FMX and for VCL you can just use `OutputDebugString` like it is shown in linked question.